# How to transform point cloud from the unity world to the screen space in the Tango's 3d reconstruction app?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I follow "Meshing with color" example at https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-mesh-color. I have tried to transform the point clouds from the unity world to the screen space (pixel cooridnates) by using Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint() function in the ExportMeshToObj() function. But the result is weird.

```
v -0.465 -0.945 -3.694288
v_screen 2788.19 2276.224 

v -0.4450556 -0.945 -3.705
v_screen 2771.131 2271.808 

v -0.465 -0.915 -3.695899 
v_screen 2783.098 2251.124 

v -0.4473471 -0.915 -3.705
v_screen 2768.094 2247.423 

v -0.435 -0.915 -3.711097 
v_screen 2757.701 2244.903 

v -0.435 -0.945 -3.709994 
v_screen 2762.624 2269.673 

v -0.405 -0.915 -3.722251 
v_screen 2732.89 2239.467 

v -0.405 -0.945 -3.722044 
v_screen 2737.645 2263.875 

v -0.375 -0.915 -3.731192 
v_screen 2708.515 2234.478 

v -0.375 -0.945 -3.732981 
v_screen 2713.082 2258.357 
...
```

Please, help me?

Comment: I am using Phab 2 Pro and the screen resolution is 1440 x 2560 pixels

Comment: The resolution that unity uses is picked in Gamewindow, it is not related to you actual screen resolution unless coded that way. Also don't provide raw data; provide the code that produced this data.